# How to import numpy when deploying django through heroku?

Tags: python, django, numpy, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Django app via Heroku. However, I do not know how to install numpy for Heroku. When I want to deploy it, it gives the following error:

```
No module named 'numpy'
```

As I said, it seems Heroku has not installed numpy by default. I have written `numpy` in my `requirements.txt` file but it seems it is not sufficient. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should work if its in your requirements. Heroku has an example project that uses miniconda in a docker image which may be of interest to you. Here is the link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#scientific-python-users it also contains information on importing dependancies.

Comment: "it seems Heroku has not installed numpy by default" of course it isn't installed by default. Why would it be?

Comment: "I have written `numpy` in my `requirements.txt` file but it seems it is not sufficient." Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: I think we should use Pipfile. That solved my problem.